# 2 Dimensional Dynamic Listview With Textbox

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

This a dynamic listview with dynamic header and rows. But the problem here is wen i try to use a textbox as

```
 xaml = "<DataTemplate><TextBox VerticalAlignment=\"Center\" TextChanged=\"{Binding " + propName + "}\" > " + propName + "</TextBox></DataTemplate>";
```

instead of a checkbox with a binding in the method CreateDataTemplate the values can't be extratcted after the btn is clicked.

Here is the code with CheckBox. So can anybody plz help me out. and i also need the values which will be inside the textbox. Thank you in advance

```
<Window x:Class="WpfListView.SalesPerson_SalesRegion_Association"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="SalesPerson_SalesRegion_Association" Height="500" Width="500">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Name="listView1" Width="400" Height="300" Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView></GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Content="ShowSelectedMapping"
            Name="btnShow" Width="150" Margin="0,10,0,0" Click="btnShow_Click"></Button>

    <TextBlock Name="textBlock1" Grid.Row="2" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

```
 public partial class SalesPerson_SalesRegion_Association : Window
{
    public SalesPerson_SalesRegion_Association()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddColumnsToListView();
        DataTable dt = DataHelper.GetRegionPersonAssociation();
        listView1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }

    private void btnShow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataView view = listView1.ItemsSource as DataView;
        DataTable userSelectionTbl = view.ToTable();

        DataTable idTable = DataHelper.GetRegionIdPersonIdMatrix();
        List<SalesRegion> lstRegion = SalesRegion.GetRegions();

        string selectedRegion = string.Empty;
        string msg = string.Empty;
        DataRow dRow=null;

        int totRows = userSelectionTbl.Rows.Count;
        int totCols = lstRegion.Count-1;
        string strTempMsg = string.Empty;
        bool isColChecked = false;
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < totRows; rowIndex++)
        {
            dRow = userSelectionTbl.Rows[rowIndex];
            strTempMsg = dRow[0].ToString() + "(" + idTable.Rows[rowIndex][0].ToString() + ")" +  " : ";

            string rgnId="";
            isColChecked = false;
            foreach (SalesRegion region in lstRegion)
            {
                if (((bool)dRow[region.RegionName]) == true)
                {
                    rgnId = idTable.Rows[rowIndex][region.RegionName].ToString();
                    strTempMsg += region.RegionName + "(" + rgnId + ")";
                    isColChecked = true;                    }
            }
            if (isColChecked == false)
            {
                strTempMsg += "  : No region selected";
            }
            strTempMsg += Environment.NewLine;

            msg += strTempMsg;
        }

        textBlock1.Text = msg;
        string tt = "t";
    }
    private void AddColumnsToListView()
    {
        List<SalesRegion> lstSalesRegion = SalesRegion.GetRegions();
        List<SalesPerson> lstSalesPerson = SalesPerson.GetSalesPersons();

        GridViewColumn colSalesPerson = new GridViewColumn();
        colSalesPerson.Header = "Sales Person";
        colSalesPerson.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("SalesPersonName");
        colSalesPerson.Width = 150;
        GridView grdView = listView1.View as GridView;
        grdView.Columns.Add(colSalesPerson);

        //Since columns are dynamic we need a data template per column
        // in which we bind the checkBox's checked property with 
        //appropriate columnName
        Dictionary<string, DataTemplate> dict = GetDataTemplates(lstSalesRegion);

        foreach (SalesRegion region in lstSalesRegion)
        {
            GridViewColumn col1 = new GridViewColumn();
            col1.Header = region.RegionName;
            DataTemplate dTempl = dict[region.RegionName];
            col1.CellTemplate = dTempl;
            grdView.Columns.Add(col1);
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<string, DataTemplate> GetDataTemplates(List<SalesRegion> lstSalesRegion)
    {
        Dictionary<string, DataTemplate> dict = new Dictionary<string, DataTemplate>();
        foreach (SalesRegion region in lstSalesRegion)
        {
            DataTemplate dTemplate = CreateDataTemplate(region.RegionName);
            dict.Add(region.RegionName, dTemplate);
        }
        return dict;
    }
    private DataTemplate CreateDataTemplate(string propName)
    {
        MemoryStream sr = null;
        ParserContext pc = null;
        string xaml = string.Empty;
        xaml = "<DataTemplate><CheckBox VerticalAlignment=\"Center\" IsChecked=\"{Binding " + propName + "}\"></CheckBox></DataTemplate>";
        sr = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xaml));
        pc = new ParserContext();
        pc.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
        pc.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
        DataTemplate datatemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(sr, pc);
        return datatemplate;
    }

} // class ends here
```

}    // DataHelper classes

```
public class SalesPerson
{
    public int SalesPersonId
    { get; set; }
    public string SalesPersonName
    { get; set; }

    public SalesPerson(int salesPersonId, string salesPersonName)
    {
        this.SalesPersonId = salesPersonId;
        this.SalesPersonName = salesPersonName;
    }

    public static List<SalesPerson> GetSalesPersons()
    {
        List<SalesPerson> lst = new List<SalesPerson>();
        lst.Add(new SalesPerson(101, "SalesPerson1"));
        lst.Add(new SalesPerson(201, "SalesPerson2"));
        lst.Add(new SalesPerson(301, "SalesPerson3"));
        lst.Add(new SalesPerson(401, "SalesPerson4"));
        lst.Add(new SalesPerson(501, "SalesPerson5"));
        return lst;
    }
} // class SalesPerson ends here

public class SalesRegion
{
    public int RegionId
    { get; set; }
    public string RegionName
    { get; set; }

    public SalesRegion(int regionId, string regionName)
    {
        this.RegionId = regionId;
        this.RegionName = regionName;
    }
    public static List<SalesRegion> GetRegions()
    {
        List<SalesRegion> lst = new List<SalesRegion>();
        lst.Add(new SalesRegion(501,"North"));
        lst.Add(new SalesRegion(502, "South"));
        lst.Add(new SalesRegion(503, "East"));
        lst.Add(new SalesRegion(504, "West"));
        lst.Add(new SalesRegion(505, "MyRegion"));
        return lst;
    }
} // class SalesRegion ends here

public class DataHelper
{
    public static DataTable GetRegionPersonAssociation()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        //Create data table structure
        // SalesPerson   Region1   Region2   Region3 ....
        DataColumn colSalesPerson = new DataColumn("SalesPersonName", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add(colSalesPerson);

        List<SalesRegion> lstRegions = SalesRegion.GetRegions();
        DataColumn colRegion = null;
        foreach (SalesRegion region in lstRegions)
        {
            colRegion = new DataColumn(region.RegionName, typeof(bool));
            dt.Columns.Add(colRegion);
        }
        //Fill data into the data table
        List<SalesPerson> personList = SalesPerson.GetSalesPersons();
        DataRow dRow = null;
        foreach (SalesPerson sp in personList)
        {
            dRow = dt.NewRow();
            dRow["SalesPersonName"] = sp.SalesPersonName;
            foreach (SalesRegion sr in lstRegions)
            {
                dRow[sr.RegionName] = false;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
        }
        return dt;
    }

    public static DataTable GetRegionIdPersonIdMatrix()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        //Create data table structure
        // SalesPerson   Region1   Region2   Region3 ....
        DataColumn colSalesPerson = new DataColumn("SalesPersonId", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add(colSalesPerson);

        List<SalesRegion> lstRegions = SalesRegion.GetRegions();
        DataColumn colRegion = null;
        foreach (SalesRegion region in lstRegions)
        {
            colRegion = new DataColumn(region.RegionName, typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add(colRegion);
        }
        //Fill data into the data table
        List<SalesPerson> personList = SalesPerson.GetSalesPersons();
        DataRow dRow = null;
        foreach (SalesPerson sp in personList)
        {
            dRow = dt.NewRow();
            dRow["SalesPersonId"] = sp.SalesPersonId;
            foreach (SalesRegion sr in lstRegions)
            {
                dRow[sr.RegionName] = sr.RegionId;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
        }
        return dt;
    }    } // class DataHelper ends here
```

Comment: Be careful: you bind a property to an event with TextChanged=\"{Binding " + propName + "}

Comment: So how do i go over it? At end wen the button is clicked i need the value of the textbox along with watever output is being showed.

Comment: do you need textboxes because you want the user be able to edit the region name? In any case I suggest you to take a look to ObservableCollection class

Comment: yes. And i want to bind the values to the textboxes wen an event is raised similarly to the checkbox but this aint happening with the textbox. So can u help me?

Comment: I ran your code: this IsChecked=\"{Binding " + propName + "}\" doesn't make sense beacuse you bind a string value to a bool property. I understand what your UX is for, but I don't understand why you want to use textboxes instead checkboxes!

Comment: The textbox will be binded with data from the database and so the data can be edited. Wen its edited i need which one was edited once the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a textbox data template like this

```
xaml = "<DataTemplate><TextBox VerticalAlignment=\"Center\" Tag=\"{Binding " + propName + ", Mode=TwoWay}\" > " + propName + "</TextBox></DataTemplate>";
```

add a style for textboxes to your listview.resources

```
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <EventSetter Event="TextChanged" Handler="TextBox_TextChanged"></EventSetter>
            </Style>
```

add the handler to your codebehind

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as TextBox).Tag = true;
    }
```

this will behave like your checkbox example.

Comment: thank you very much. Really appreciate for the help. I do still have one more issue with this. How do i get the values from the textbox which are edited.

Comment: you need to upgrade the object you bind to every cell. Not a simple boolean, but a structure like bool | string, so you can bind boolean to the Tag property of the textbox and string to the Text property (please consider to mark the answer as accepted)

Comment: Sorry to bother you michele but i gt the answer. truly nice of you to help out. Thank you again.

Comment: hey michele i just wanted to know how can we add values in the rows from the database into the textbox.

Comment: xaml = "<DataTemplate><TextBox VerticalAlignment=\"Center\" Tag=\"{Binding " + propName + ", Mode=TwoWay}\" Text=\"{Binding " + valueFromDatabase+ ", Mode=TwoWay}\" ></TextBox></DataTemplate>";

Comment: i m really sorry not able to reply you soon due to circumstances.anyways thank michele  I did this already but the problem is you know when i click on the button the method :    private void btnShow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
at:                                                                    Id = idTable.Rows[rowIndex][region.RegionId].ToString();          has error saying it can't find the column but if i use a autoincrement id in the binding it's able to find it. Can you please help me out.

Comment: This happen incase any updates are done inside the textbox. Otherwise it's works just fine.

Comment: hey michele thank anyways. gt the answer for it too. did a little bit of adjustment here and there. But still gt one question in mind. Is it possible to bind the header with an id and such that wen the button is clicked we get the header id instead of the header. Thanks